# VM load date but keep in memory when switching windows

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

Working with a Xamarin.Forms app (with UWP). I'm very new to MVVM and this is my first real project working with it. I get how this is better but honestly, finding good videos have been difficult. Almost all of the videos are for people that have either worked with MVVM previously or they talk about a framework that has been sunset. I'm currently using no framework for this project.

I'm was thinking of using a singleton but I have seen many post about how that is a bad programming mistake. I have a VM that loads a single json file that stores between 1 and 50 models. It loads the models into an observablecollection that gets passed to a ListView. If a user clicks on a line, I want it to load a different page with that specific item. You will be allowed to update the model and if you click "save". It needs to take the model and overwrite the item in the observablecollection with the new data. The part that I'm getting lost is when I switch contentpage, the VM that was loaded also goes away. I just don't know the proper way to handle this because it recreates the VM when I navigate to he new page (Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Settings()). Normally, that isn't a horrible approach but I will be loading data from a server and I just thought reloading the data again from the cloud would be a waste of bandwidth because the json file is 1 MB and this would easily approach the gigabyte bandwidth for this one little button over a month. What would be the best way to not have to reload the data and keep the data a live?

Also, if you have a recommendations for MVVM for Xamarin.Forms for newbies. I would be happy to watch more videos!

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You need to post code ([mcve]) that demonstrates the problem you're having.  Based on just the description its impossible to say what exactly you are doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't include code because my question isn't directly related to my code but how things are setup and moving between multiple contentpage but not reloading the ViewModel when modifying the data in them.

Comment: You are in complete control of how the VM is loaded. If it is not behaving as you want, then you are free to change it.

Comment: I understand that, I'm on window A that loads the VM and shows a listview. User clicks on an item an gets sent to window B with the data from the selected row from the grid. User updates the data and saves. This would kick back to window A and instead of reloading or creating basically creating a new VM because the original window A is gone, I wanted to see if it was possible to keep the VM in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.For Moving between multiple pages and use the VM,like Jason said you are in complete control of the VM.Below is the code snippets moving from mainPage to detailPage.        
    
    private async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //selected item
        var s =collectionView.SelectedItem as NoteModel;
        //transfer data via viewmodel constructor
        var detailVM = new DetailPageViewModel
        {
            NoteTexter = s.Text
        };

        var detailPage = new DetailPage
        {
            BindingContext = detailVM
        };

        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(detailPage);
    }

2.For keeping the data live in Xamarin forms app, you have a couple options: Files and local database.
  You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/
```